# Remove or replace the absolute path of an EAssertionFailed with a relative path or the file name only?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Is there some way to remove or replace the absolute path of an EAssertionFailed  error message? I would like to not include the entire path to not indirectly reveal where the source has been compiled and make the message independent of that location. Preferably the relative path to the project root or to the DPR file, or the source file name only would be included in the error message instead.

---

Program output:

```
EAssertionFailed: Assertion failed (C:\Users\User\Documents\
Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Project3.dpr, line 12)
```

Project3.dpr

```
program Project3;

{$AppType Console}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  try
    Assert(False);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      ReadLn;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Write your own handler ([AssertErrorProc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AssertErrorProc)), or hook the existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace or hook the AssertErrorProc and alter or suppress the filename and line number information.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysConst,
  System.SysUtils;

   procedure CustomAssertErrorHandler(const Message, Filename: string; LineNumber: Integer; ErrorAddr: Pointer);

   var
      FileNameOnly : string;

   begin
      FileNameOnly := ExtractFileName(FileName);

      if Message <> '' then
        raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt(SAssertError,
          [Message, FileNameOnly, LineNumber]) at ErrorAddr
      else
        raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt(SAssertError,
          [SAssertionFailed, FileNameOnly, LineNumber]) at ErrorAddr;
   end;

begin
   AssertErrorProc := CustomAssertErrorHandler;

 try
    Assert(False);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      ReadLn;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

---

**Update**: Here is the questioner's solution which converts from the full project path to a relative path:

```
program Project3;

{$AppType Console}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysConst,
  System.SysUtils;

procedure AssertErrorHandler(const Msg, Filename: String; 
  LineNumber: Integer; ErrorAddr: Pointer);

{$Region '$Include ProjectRoot.pas.inc'}

const
   ProjectRoot = 'C:\Users\';

{$EndRegion}

var
  Temp: String;

begin
  if (ProjectRoot <> '') and Filename.StartsWith(ProjectRoot) then
    Temp := Filename.Remove(0, ProjectRoot.Length)
  else
    Temp := ExtractFileName(Filename);

  if Msg <> '' then
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateResFmt(@SAssertError,
      [Msg, Temp, LineNumber]) at ErrorAddr
  else
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateResFmt(@SAssertError,
      [SAssertionFailed, Temp, LineNumber]) at ErrorAddr;
end;

begin
  try
    AssertErrorProc := AssertErrorHandler;
//    Assert(False);
    Assert(False, 'Custom message');
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      ReadLn;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Well, when I edited the answer, I meant to integrate the option to have a relative path and I meant to hint the supply of the project root path by a CI system, to make it a little bit more comprehensive to the question. I accepted the original answer. But by review my proposal is re-edited and separate, which duplicates code and just seems to add noise. So, for me to learn, wasn't I supposed to edit this here on SO? Am I to answer my own question instead?

Comment: @Max answering your own question is perfectly acceptable on SO.

Comment: @Max: Yes, your code addresses an addition detail from your question.  But, I feel that my answer is more straight forward; demonstrating the main point of your question: How to enhance/replace the behavior of the `Assert` command.  The additional details you included might confuse a less experienced reader down the road: perhaps they might think that the CI code is also required in order to override the `Assert` behavior. (And thus, trigger duplicate questions to be posted) So, that's why I decided to include your code separately, noting what the additional code was adding to the solution....

Comment: @Max: So, I propose we leave things as they are.   **But**, if you feel strongly that your code should be the main answer, then I urge you to compose your own answer and change the accepted answer over to yours (yes, you can switch the accepted answer).   If you do, then I will, of course, edit mine back to its original state (without the "update").  And, I'll leave it to the SO community to decide if my answer should be deleted altogether (by down voting it beyond -3).